# TypeError during vectorization with sparse hstack

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, vectorization

I am trying to run sparse hstack to join a a column of features and a preprocessed text column created by TF-IDF. I want to do this so I can use all columns as features in a classifier.

My current data-frame is:

| article_id | article_word_count | recommendations | comment_word_count | start_question |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5adb535d06 | 0.99999 | 0.0 | 0.357388 | 1 |

| question_mark | comment | pub_length | type_of_material_News |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ['mind', 'big', 'threat', 'pose', 'facebook'] | 0.00106 | 1 |

I have the following code for data handling:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df['comment'] = df['comment'].apply(eval)
features = df.drop(columns=['recommendations'])  
y = df['recommendations'].to_numpy()
```

I have the following code for vectorization where the error occurs:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=identity_tokenizer, ngram_range=(1, 1), lowercase=False)  
X_ef = features.drop(columns='comment')
tfidf_text = tfidf.fit_transform(features['comment'])
X = sparse.hstack([X_ef,tfidf_text]).tocsr()
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
line 51, in upcast
    raise TypeError('no supported conversion for types: %r' % (args,))
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'), dtype('float64'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to drop the article ID as this could not be converted to a float. Then I added the following code, which worked:

```
X = sparse.hstack([X_ef.astype(float),tfidf_text]).tocsr()
```